# What's the meaning of privately inheriting an abstract base class in C++

Tags: c++, inheritance, chromium

In C++, we have a base class containing purely public pure-virtual member functions, referred as the abstract base class. Then we define a subclass of it, but using private inheritance. We know that this is an implementation inheritance but in this case, what is inherited is the *interface*. Yes, this question sounds very strange -- You use private inheritance to inherit a pure interface!

Examples exist in the practice, even in industrial code base like Chromium. [Here](https://cs.chromium.org/chromium/src/third_party/blink/renderer/platform/loader/fetch/raw_resource.h?type=cs&q=raw_resou&sq=package:chromium&g=0&l=160) we got a `RawResourceClient` as the abstract base class. Note its member functions are not pure-virtual, but virtual with an empty body, and this is very similar to pure-virtual. In that webpage, you can find a *Subclasses* tab. Here are a few classes that privately inherited from it:

```
class InspectorResourceContentLoader::ResourceClient final
    : public GarbageCollectedFinalized<
          InspectorResourceContentLoader::ResourceClient>,
      private RawResourceClient {
  USING_GARBAGE_COLLECTED_MIXIN(ResourceClient);

class CORE_EXPORT ThreadableLoader final
    : public GarbageCollectedFinalized<ThreadableLoader>,
      private RawResourceClient {
  USING_GARBAGE_COLLECTED_MIXIN(ThreadableLoader);
```

My question is, *what is the clever trick behind the scense?* Is it using `friend` tricks?

Comment: If you can't find the subclasses tab in the link, click the class name `RawResourceClient` and it will show up below the main code view.

Answer (score 0):

Such a class (or one of its friends, of course) can pass `this`, suitably converted to a pointer to the private base, to any component accepting such a pointer, allowing its implementation of the interface to be used but only in its selected contexts.

Comment: In other words, if the derived class sees fit, it can also define a method to convert itself to the base pointer/reference.

Comment: @cgsdfc: Of course, and that could be used as a (somewhat haphazard) means of allowing only “explicit conversions” to the base.

Comment: Ther is also something as 'the empty base class' optimization

Comment: @ArneJ: Yes, although most applications of it that come to mind don’t benefit from private inheritance.